# Creating dataset_dicts from csv files to train Detectron2 object detection task

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, detectron

**Hello people.**

I want to create a dataset_dict to train my detectron2 model for object detection.
I have .csv annotations and corresponding images.
For each image i have multiple annotations and with help of a loop i get thoose annotations and append them to object.
I have a dataset_dicts array and when i try to append my annotation information to array i got a problem.
I will share my code down below and my results for this code.

```
from detectron2.structures import BoxMode
import pandas as pd

def getdataset_dicts(path):
  files = os.listdir(path)


  categories = {'cat1':1, 'cat2':2, 'cat3':3, 'cat4':4, 'cat5':5}
  dataset_dicts = []
  for file in files:
    
    image_id = int(file.split(".")[0])
    if file[-4:] == '.jpg':

      filename = os.path.join(path,file)
      height, width = cv2.imread(filename).shape[:2]

      record = {}
      record["file_name"] = file
      record["image_id"] = image_id
      record["height"] = height
      record["width"] = width

      annotation_file_name = file.split('.')[0]
      annotation_file_path = os.path.normpath(annotation_file_name + '.csv')
      annotation_path = os.path.join(path,annotation_file_path)
      df = pd.read_csv(annotation_path)

      for _, row in df.iterrows():
        objs = []
        category = row["category"]
        obj = {
          "bbox": [row['xmin'], row['ymin'], row['xmax'], row['ymax']],
          "bbox_mode": BoxMode.XYXY_ABS,
          "category_id" : categories[cat]
        }
        objs.append(obj)
        record['annotations'] = objs
        print(record)
      dataset_dicts.append(record)
  return dataset_dicts
getdataset("/content/drive/MyDrive/datasets/test")
```

[This is result when i run my code. You can also see a few of my record objects. I think they are all fine. they match to csv data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMTvV.png)

I need to add all my records to dataset_dicts array and i tried several things and failed.

Thank you from advance. Have a nice day all.

Comment: I just see that all down when i call function i shared wrong it is not getdataset("/content/drive/MyDrive/datasets/test") but getdataset_dicts("/content/drive/MyDrive/datasets/test")  this.